# How to have advanced doctrine configuration in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, dbal

Reading these docs:

[Doctrine DBAL Configuration with Symfony](http://brentertainment.com/other/docs/book/doctrine/dbal.html)

[Doctrine ORM Configuration with Symfony](http://brentertainment.com/other/docs/book/doctrine/orm.html)

[Doctrine Configuration with Symfony](http://brentertainment.com/other/docs/reference/configuration/doctrine.html)

I created this and added to /src/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.php of my generated bundle:
[My Configuration code](http://pastebin.com/kzbPdpyg)

But I get the error:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\LogicException]
>   Container extension "doctrine" is not registered

What more I missed to do? I probably have to add that I did NOT remove the default orm/dbal settings in /app/config/config.yml.
Also I have no idea what 'read' and what 'host'=>'from_user_config.db' is, I copied/pasted from a third-party application and how to inject db credentials from a separate file into this services.php?

Comment: Do you have the DoctrineBundle enabled in the AppKernel?